# How to Update HTML using Node JS from MYSQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, web

**Question**

How can i change my HTML data in the files via node JS i am not using EJS or any view engine I have a views folders where all the files are .js files returning HTML how can i change the data from the node server which selects the MYSQL data for example if i have

I have tried using res.send but it changes the whole file how can i change for example on the about page /aboutus

`<h1 id='name'></h1>`

How can i add data from the server to edit that file?
thanks

For those who can't quite understand what i am saying is i have a server side which is meant to retrieve an html name for example david and i have a views folder containing js files like home.js which returns html value to the index.html file i want to change the heading tag in html like the code above i want 'David' to be put in the h1 tag

Comment: research `res.render`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not been able to understand perfectly what you want to do ...
But I believe that in any case to create a dynamic client server infrastructure you could use two methods:

- by creating an endpoint that returns the data in json or xml format from the database, and replacing your DOM elements  with the real data

example:

Express Backend example

```
app.get('/api/user', async function(req, res) {
 const userdata = await getUserData()
  res.send(JSON.stringify(userdata));
});
```

Front end example:

```
fetch('http://MYAPI.com/api/user')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data =>{
    document.getElementById("username").innerHTML = data.username;
    document.getElementById("email").innerHTML = data.email;
});
```

- by converting your html files into [handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/#what-is-handlebars) (for example) and replacing the handlebars tags with real data, then return html ready to be rendered.

Comment: I am trying to Retrieve Data from mysql on the server side and change for example a heading tag in my client side views folder

Comment: Ok, so you just need to create an endpoint with express that returns the data retrieved from the database in json format, then on the frontend side make a request to this endpoint to retrieve the json data and then replace them via DOM. (see example)

Comment: Thank you soo much it worked really appreciate it